# How to decide if a system of equations is zero-dimensional?

Tags: field-theory, systems-of-equations, ideals

I am working with a multivariate system of polynomial equations over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and I need to decide if the system is zero-dimensional. As far as I know, a finite field is never algebraically closed. So I want to consider whether my system of equations has finitely many solutions in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

I was looking at the available mathematical software for that and stumbled upon zero-dimensional ideals.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Is it true that if the ideal generated by a set of polynomials is zero-dimensional that means that the system of these polynomials is also zero-dimensional?

Thank you!

Edit: @freakish pointed out that I need to define what I mean by a zero-dimensional ideal. I consider the ideal to be zero-dimensional if the associated variety is a finite set.

Comment: How can you consider an equation over some finite field as an equation over $\mathbb{C}$? Typically "zero-dimensional over $k$" means "finitely many solutions over the algebraic closure of $k$". This makes sense since a finite field cannot be algebraically closed. Also what do you mean by "zero-dimensional ideal"? Do you mean that Krull dimension of $R/I$ is $0$?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will update my question to include algebraic closure instead of the filed of complex numbers. What I mean is that the associated variety $V(I)$ is a finite set for the ideal $I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's fix the notation and concepts. Let $k$ be any field that you like, finite or infinite, algebraically closed or not.

By Hilbert theorem, if $R$ is a Noetherian ring, and $x_1$, ..., $x_n$, some variables, then every ideal in the ring $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ has a finite generating set. And fields are trivially Noetherian rings. Alternatively see Theorem 4, Section 5, Chapter 2 of [1].

Now, let $R$ be the ring $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with your favourite field sitting for $k$. For any ideal $I$ of $R$, there are finitely many polynomials $f_1$, ..., $f_m$ such that $I=\langle f_1,\dots,f_m\rangle$.

For any polynomial $f\in R$, let $V(f)$ be the set of points $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in k^n$ such that by substituting $x_i=a_i$ in $f$, it vanishes. i.e. $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$. For a set $S\subseteq R$, let $V(S)=\cap_{f\in S}V(f)$, the common solutions to all members of $S$.

It is easy to show that $V(\langle f_1,\dots,f_m\rangle)=V(\lbrace f_1,\dots,f_m\rbrace)$. So the answer to "**Question**" in your post, with the definition in the '*Edit*' line after it, is yes. There is no difference between the variety (solutions) of the ideal generated by a set of polynomials and the variety of the generating set. And therefore $V(I)$ being zero-dimensional where $I=\langle f_1,\dots,f_m\rangle$ is exactly the same as saying $V(f_1,\dots,f_m)$ is zero-dimensional.

Even if you consider solutions in $\bar{k}^n$ where $\bar{k}$ is algebraic closure of $k$, the same simple proof of $V(\langle f_1,\dots,f_m\rangle)=V(\lbrace f_1,\dots,f_m\rbrace)$ holds. So the same positive answer to your "**Question**".

But the title of your question together with the line above your "**Question**", to me has a different meaning. It means how computationally check a polynomial ideal is zero-dimensional, or equivalently a system of equations has finitely many solutions.

Note that an ideal being zero-dimensional means that the Krull dimension of $\frac{R}{I}$ is $0$, as mentioned by @freakish. The corresponding variety being a finite set of points is not the definition of $I$ being zero-dimensional, but a consequence! So don't mix definitions and implications. You can read Chapter 9 of [1] as a good reference and as a start point to learn about dimension of varieties and polynomial ideals.

Now if you want to use software, there are many options. If you are a Maple user, then **HilbertDimension** command from **PolynomialIdeals** or **Groebner** packages. https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Groebner%2fHilbertDimension. And remember that when the characteristic of the coefficient field is non-zero, add the option `characteristic=p`.

Or if you want a free software, you can use try *Singular*. The command **dim** does this https://www.singular.uni-kl.de/Manual/4-3-1/sing_233.htm#SEC273. In Singular you always define the ring, so you already have given the characteristic of the field before using `dim` command.

[1]: Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms, David A. Cox, John Little, Donal O’Shea, Springer, 4th edition, 2015, DOI: [10.1007/978-3-319-16721-3](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-16721-3)